# MySQL slow with large text fields in table

Tags: mysql, performance

We're having a weird problem with MySQL (and also MariaDB). A simple database with 2 tables (InnoDB engine), both containing (among a few others) 3 or 4 text columns with XML data approx. 1-5kB in size.
Each table has around 40000 rows and no indexes except those for foreign keys.

The weird part is running select statements. The XML columns are NOT used anywhere inside select statement (select, where, order, group, ...), yet they slow down execution. If those columns are null, select statement executes in less than 2 second, but if they contain data, execution time jumps to around 20 seconds. Why is that?!

This is a script that generates an example behaving like described above:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
    id                  bigint(20)      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1                bigint(20)      NULL,
    col2                bigint(20)      NULL,
    date1               datetime        NULL,
    largeString1        text            NULL,
    largeString2        text            NULL,
    largeString3        text            NULL,
    largeString4        text            NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE tableB (
    id              bigint(20)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1            bigint(20)  NULL,
    col2            varchar(45) NULL,
    largeString1    text        NULL,
    largeString2    datetime    NULL,
    largeString3    text        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

fillTables:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `fillTables`(
    numRows INT
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE j INT;
    DECLARE largeString TEXT;
    SET i = 1;

    START TRANSACTION;

    WHILE i < numRows DO
        SET j = 1;
        SET largeString = '';
        WHILE j <= 100 DO
            SET largeString = CONCAT(largeString, (SELECT UUID()));
            SET j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;

        INSERT INTO tableA (id, col1, col2, date1, largeString1,
                           largeString2, largeString3, largeString4)
           VALUES (i, FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 2), numRows - i, 
                   date_sub(now(), INTERVAL i hour),
                   largeString, largeString, largeString, largeString);
        INSERT INTO tableB (id, col1, col2, largeString1,
                           largeString2, largeString3)
           VALUES (numRows - i, i, (SELECT UUID()),
                   largeString, largeString, largeString);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    COMMIT;

    ALTER TABLE tableA ADD FOREIGN KEY (col2) REFERENCES tableB(id);
    CREATE INDEX idx_FK_tableA_tableB ON tableA(col2);
    ALTER TABLE tableB ADD FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES tableA(id);
    CREATE INDEX idx_FK_tableB_tableA ON tableB(col1);

END ;;
```

test

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
    _param1     bigint
    ,_dateFrom  datetime
    ,_dateTo    datetime
)
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        a.id
        ,DATE(a.date1) as date
        ,COALESCE(b2.col2, '') as guid
        ,COUNT(*) as count
    FROM
        tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b1 ON b1.col1 = a.id
        LEFT JOIN tableB b2 ON b2.id = a.col2
    WHERE
        a.col1 = _param1
        AND (_dateFrom IS NULL OR DATE(a.date1) BETWEEN DATE(_dateFrom) AND DATE(_dateTo))
    GROUP BY
        a.id
        ,DATE(a.date1)
        ,b2.col2
    ;

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

To populate the tables with random data use

```
call fillTables(40000);
```

Stored procedure used for retrieving data:

```
call test(2, null, null);
```

Also, MSSQL executes the select statement in a fraction of a second without any table optimization (even without foreign keys defined).

UPDATE:

SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables:

```
'CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `largeString1` text,
  `largeString2` text,
  `largeString3` text,
  `largeString4` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_FK_tableA_tableB` (`col2`),
  CONSTRAINT `tableA_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`col2`) REFERENCES `tableB` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'


'CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `largeString1` text,
  `largeString2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `largeString3` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_FK_tableB_tableA` (`col1`),
  CONSTRAINT `tableB_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`col1`) REFERENCES `tableA` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Comment: *and no indexes except those for foreign keys* -  Here is the problem. Use explain and figure out the right indexes to use for the select statement. Indexes with dates and the join conditions should speed things up

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the indexes _that were implicitly created for the `FOREIGN KEYs`_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both tables need `INDEX(col1)`.  Without it, these need table scans:

```
WHERE a.col1 = _param1

ON b1.col1 = a.id
```

For `a` this would be 'covering', hence faster:

```
INDEX(col1, date1, id, col2)
```

Don't use `LEFT` unless you need it.

Try not to hide columns in functions; it prevents using indexes for them:

```
DATE(a.date1) BETWEEN ...
```

This might work for that:

```
    a.date1 >= DATE(_dateFrom)
AND a.date1  < DATE(_dateTo) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

As for the mystery of 20s vs 2s -- Did you run each timing test twice?  The first time is often bogged down with I/O; the second is memory-bound.

**ROW_FORMAT**

In InnoDB there are 4 `ROW_FORMATs`; they mostly differ in how they handle big strings (`TEXT`, `BLOB`, etc).  You mentioned that the query ran faster with `NULL` strings than with non-null strings.  With the default `ROW_FORMAT`, some or all of the XML strings is stored with the rest of the columns.  After some limit, the rest is put in another block(s).

If a large field is `NULL`, then it takes almost no space.

With `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` (see `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE`), a non-null column will tend to be pushed to other blocks instead of making the main part of the record bulky.

This has the effect of allowing more rows to fit in a single block (except for the overflow).  That, in turn, allows certain queries to run faster since they can get more information with fewer I/Os.

Read the documentation, I think you need these:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

In reading the documentation, you will run across `COMPRESSED`.  Although this would shrink the XML by perhaps 3:1, there are other issues.  I don't know whether it would end up being better or not.

**Buffer pool**

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of *available* RAM.

Comment: Yes, I realize that even 2 seconds is way too long for this kind of select, but optimizing it is not really a part of my question. And yes, I ran it multiple times and execution times were the same. The problem are those "largeString" columns that are NEVER used in select, yet they slow down everything. Why is that?

Comment: Rick, thank you. Although your answer didn't help directly, your explanation of InnoDB led me to this article that explains our problem perfectly: http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.si/2010/11/handling-long-textsblobs-in-innodb-1-to.html

Comment: Yoshinori does good stuff.  But I can't get to that page because Norton thinks that site is 'dangerous'.

Comment: Weird ... windows defender says nothing :) It's just his blog, so there should be nothing dangerous, unless Blogger was compromised.